# xcodebuild command for Xcode 8 beta to set provisioning profile and team ID

Tags: command-line, xcodebuild, xcode8

I am not able to build a project from command line in the latest Xcode 8 beta version. Can you please let me know the "`xcodebuild`" commands for Xcode 8 beta version to build a project through command line. previous commands which we used in previous versions of Xcode does not work now. Every time it throws and error : "Check dependencies
Signing for MyTestApp3 requires a development team. Select a development team in the Target Editor.
Code signing is required for product type '`Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0`'"

Command i used to build - `xcodebuild -project MyTestApp3.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release clean build DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym DSTROOT=build GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=build OBJROOT=build SYMROOT=build PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER= CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: Our Distribution Certificate"`.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try DEVELOPMENT_TEAM command line parameter?

It can also be set in Xcode (General and Build Settings tabs).

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39559864/1453089)!

Mybe you also want to know how to get the 10-digit team id. Well, I found it in the output of command

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -project <YourProject> |grep DEVELOPMENT_TEAM
```