# Add Provisioning profile without adding account in xcode: 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode8

I have created a new project in XCode and now I want to sign in with development mode.It asks me to login with developer account. But I don't have account, I have provisioning profiles and certificates. I have tried many ways but they din't work. I tried to off auto signing but i don't get it also.

Please check this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: try double clicking on provisioning profile file in finder to add into xcode

Answer (score 0):

How did you create provisioning profile and certificates if you don't have a developer account?

A developer account is needed, since the profiles and certificates would be "linked" to that specific account.

Comment: thanks for your answer. my client gives me P.profile now i want to add that profile ?

Comment: You should ask your client to add you to the Team of the developer account specifying that he needs to activate the permissions related to profiles and certificates. More details here https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: Technically, you don't need the developer account as long as the developer provides you the signing identity files.  Of course, Apple is really pushing people to use automatic code signing, because it takes away a lot of pain from the manual code signing process.  Note that you can use a free developer account, so there's no cost involved.  Of course, if your client won't add you as a developer role on the account, you can see my answer about how to do manual code signing with a new Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Xcode 8 doesn't allow you to easily switch to manual code signing for new projects (which default to automatic code signing, and that requires an Apple ID for a valid developer account).  If you want to switch the project to allow manual code signing (so you can use the code signing identity provided by your client), you must make some manual changes to your .cxodeproj file.

First, make sure you have closed the Xcode project. Then, find your xcode project (.xcodeproj) in Finder and right click on the icon, then select "Show Package Contents".  Inside the Finder window, find the "project.pbxproj" file.  Right click on that file and open the file in your text editor of choice (you can open this in Xcode).  Find all occurences where you find the text "ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;" and replace it with "ProvisioningStyle = Manual;".  Save the pbxproj file and then re-open the .xcodeproj in Xcode. You should now see options for specifying the code signing identity in your project settings.

You can find some more details about this, including ways to script this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39598052/3708242).