# Xcode 8, xcodebuild, multiple bundle ID and Provisioning Profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild

I have to start by saying if I build using Xcode, everything is fine. My goal is to use xcodebuild with Jenkins so that I can have automated builds with multiple environments. I am really confused with how Xcode 8 works with automated signing.

I started by looking at this: [Use xcodebuild (Xcode 8) and automatic signing in CI (Travis/Jenkins) environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500634/use-xcodebuild-xcode-8-and-automatic-signing-in-ci-travis-jenkins-environmen)

Things started to work when I did this. However, now when I added a new bundle ID and PP, I started to get the following errors. Also, the previous build ID doesn't work either:

## Building

> 23:06:50 Check dependencies
>
> 23:06:50 [BCEROR]No profiles for 'com.x.y.z' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.x.y.z'.
>
> 23:06:50 [BCEROR]Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

## Archiving

> 23:06:51 No profiles for 'com.x.y.z' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.x.y.z'.
>
> 23:06:51 Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'
>
> 23:06:51 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

This is what I am doing:

```sh
#if the directory exist, run the command
if [ -d "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" ]; then
    xattr -rc ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
fi

#Unlock keychain
security unlock-keychain -p xxx ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

#Build .xarchive
xcodebuild -project ${WORKSPACE}/PATH.xcodeproj \
           -scheme X \
           -configuration Release \
           clean \
           archive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/.../archive.xcarchive \
           DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=XXX

#Unlock keychain
security unlock-keychain -p x ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

#Exporting to .ipa
    xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/XXX/archive.xcarchive \
           -exportOptionsPlist /XXXX/exportOptions.plist \
           -exportPath ${WORKSPACE}/XXXX/Output/${Environment} \
           PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="ENVIRONMENT_PP"
```

Comment: Did you tried archive build using xcode to confirm all the required profiles and certificates are installed on the machine?

Comment: Yea I went to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> On each team, Download All Profiles

Comment: Did you tried archive build using Xcode?

Comment: I can using automatic signing

Answer (score 0):

So I am using Unity to generate the xcode project. What I did to fix it:

In Unity, disable the automatic signing and specify the Provisioning profile hash, (I got the hash from using the editor view, and copied the value to the script):

```
 private static readonly string UDIDProfileHash = "HASH";

 PlayerSettings.iOS.appleEnableAutomaticSigning = false;
 PlayerSettings.iOS.appleDeveloperTeamID = "TEAMID";
 PlayerSettings.iOS.iOSManualProvisioningProfileID = UDIDProfileHash;
```

For the Xcodebuild syntax I removed specifying the Provisioning profile:

```sh
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="ENVIRONMENT_PP"
```