# Automatic signing for iOS app in VSTS Xcode Task

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops

I am creating .ipa file form VSTS and getting the following error:

Code Signing Error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode
2018-02-26T05:06:35.4093530Z Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.digitalmettle.alcami' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.digitalmettle.alcami'.
2018-02-26T05:06:35.4114650Z Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

[image]

How can I add the developer account in Xcode?

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition? There are [Install Apple Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate) and [Install Apple Provisioning Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile) tasks.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I am using Install Apple Provisioning Profile task and Xcode task where I have enabled the automatic signing in Xcode. I have also added the screenshot in the question

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT: Find the logs here: https://digitalmettle-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/twinkle/Eby_9Tt9nNZOqXJU2UD1jM4BJqPzHF9Ofjhy3AfBiCs-lw?e=tzfxZE

Comment: What's the result if you call xcodebuild command with automatic sign argument (CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic) manually? This thread may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500634/use-xcodebuild-xcode-8-and-automatic-signing-in-ci-travis-jenkins-environmen

Comment: manually I am creating the .ipa from Xcode tool in my mac system. I didn't try this with commands.I am doing the same steps in VSTS task Xcode. Also, added the certificates and provisioning profiles tasks in VSTS. But it is throwing the mentioned error :( . Kindly suggest something.

Comment: It is related to the automatic sign without specify the provisioning profiles, with manual signing way, you can specify Provisioning profile UUID. Just try to call xcodebuild command to automatic sign code and check the result.

Comment: I run These two commands locally and it worked:                     
 xcodebuild -workspace Alcami.xcworkspace -scheme Alcami -sdk iphoneos -configuration AppStoreDistribution archive -archivePath $PWD/build/Alcami.xcarchive

xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/Alcami.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -exportPath $PWD/build  should I disbale the provisioning task from VSTS?

Comment: The issue is related to build command (buildaction) instead of archive, try to    specify build as buildaction.

Comment: I have specified the build as buildaction in VSTS Xcode task.

Comment: Call `xcodebuild build CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic xxx` command manually and check the result.

Comment: I run this command and it worked manually :                                                           xcodebuild -workspace Alcami.xcworkspace \
            -scheme CLI \
            -destination generic/platform=iOS build CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent when build in VSTS?

Comment: I am using Hosted Mac preview agent.

Comment: Try to choose Manual signing in Signing Style box and specify Signing identity and Provisioning profile UUID. (Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/mobile/app-signing?tabs=apple-install-during-build#sign-your-apple-ios-macos-tvos-or-watchos-app)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165883/discussion-between-twinkle-and-starian-chen-msft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work with the automatic signing. I had to manage this with the manual signing. see the attached screenshot.

Add these tasks in the build: 
[image]

And in xcode task enable the manual signing:

[image]